# Undefined behavior of std::string when c_str() used

Tags: c++, string, char, copy

The following code example behavior is undefined..

```
char * getName()
{
   std::string name("ABCXYZ");
   return name.c_str();
}
```

This is because name goes out of scope. But I wanted to understand how it is different when we return a std::string and does not it produce undefined behavior ?

Comment: If you return it (the `std::string`) by value it gets copied/moved out, so it's not UB.

Comment: In all likelihood, returning a `std::string` wouldn't even copy anything; the return value would be created in place when possible. C++17 even guarantees this sometimes. If that can't be done, the string will at least be moved out instead of copied. There's really not much to worry about.

Comment: It's a well known C++ guideline that you should never return local objects by reference (or pointer). You can read more about it in Effective C++, but David Schwartz's explanation covers most of it.

Comment: You should either turn up the warning level of your compiler or get a new one.  Your code [should not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ac63ecbb512f383).

Answer (score 5):

When you `return` a value, the value is safely returned to the caller. That's what the `return` statement does.

In the case where you call `c_str`, the value you're returning is a pointer into the string. Once the string is destroyed, that pointer now points to nothing in particular. The value *is* safely returned, it's just that there's nothing you can do with it safely.

The value of a `string` is the contents of the string. So in that case, it is the contents of the string that gets passed to the caller. One could say that the primary purpose of the `std::string` class is to provide an object whose value is the contents of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because *return* instruction copies or moves (*see C++11*) the object returned.

With this code:

```
std::string getName() {
   std::string name("ABCXYZ");
   return name;
}
```

the string *name* will be copied and returned to the caller.

With your code, *return* will make a copy of a *pointer* (because your function returns a pointer), not of the pointed object. That'll produce an UB.

Comment: Might be copied. Modern compilers have a large pool of tricks they use to avoid copying data. Pop "Return Value Optimisation"  and "Copy Elision" into the web search of your choice if you're interested in learning more about two of the most common tricks.

Comment: @user4581301 I know very well those "tricks". I didn't mentioned them because OT. Anyway what I was saying it just regards standard, let's out platform-depend aspects ;-)